# Migration doesn't add column to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have two models `Artist` and `Painting`.

I added the following migration and executed `rake db:migrate`

```
class AddArtistReferenceToPaintings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  self.up do 
    change_table :paintings do |t|
      t.references :artist
    end  
  end
end
```

This doesn't change anything in the database. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems correct .

Did you already run this migration and added this latter ? If yes then create new one OR delete version from schema_migrations .

Way :
To add a foreign key column

```
change_table(:suppliers) do |t|
  t.references :company
end
```

It creates a company_id(integer) column

To add a polymorphic foreign key column

```
change_table(:suppliers) do |t|
  t.belongs_to :company, :polymorphic => true
end
```

It creates company_type(varchar) and company_id(integer) columns .

For further detail refer the [link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html).

Comment: I tried this too with a new migration. Still doesn't change the database.

Comment: Simply add it like : (add_column :paintings, :artist_id, :integer)

Comment: OR (add_column :paintings, :artist_id, :integer ,:references=>"artists")

Comment: This worked! Just weird that my original migration didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
t.belongs_to :artist
```

instead

```
t.references :artist
```

But your variant should work too, if you test in irb console. Run 'reload' to update.

Comment: Please, attach log of your migration

Comment: ==  ReferenceArtistFromPaintings: reverting ===================================
==  ReferenceArtistFromPaintings: reverted (0.0000s) ==========================

==  ReferenceArtistFromPaintings: migrating ===================================
==  ReferenceArtistFromPaintings: migrated (0.0000s) ==========================

Comment: This is from the new migration Vik recommended.